# Docker MySQL client on alpine container doesn't execute commands or generate logs

Tags: docker, mysql-connector

I'm trying to run a MySQL client container using Docker. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client
ENTRYPOINT ["mysql"]
```

I build the image successfully and then run it using the command:

```
docker run my-mysql-client -h <host> -P <port> -D <database> -u <user> -p <password> -e "MY SQL COMMANDS"
```

However, the container simply exits without executing any commands on the database, and I don't see any log files generated.

I have made sure to replace the placeholders `<host>`, `<port>`, `<database>`, `<user>`, `<password>`, and `"MY SQL COMMANDS"` with the appropriate values.

Am I missing something in my Dockerfile or the way I'm running the container? Why is the MySQL client not executing the commands or generating any logs? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no space between `-p` and `password`.  Can it actually connect to the server.

Comment: @IdanB https://github.com/Logiqx/mysql-client

Comment: @MaximColesnic how to use it in the command line inorder to send a sql please?

Comment: @danblack there's a space already

Comment: `docker run my-mysql-client -h <host> -P <port> -D <database> -u <user> -p<password> -e "MY SQL COMMANDS"` - *no* space